# Reducing a list of UnaryOperators in Java 8

Tags: java, functional-programming, java-8

What is the preferred way of reducing a list of UnaryOperators in Java 8 till they represent one UnaryOperator that I can call apply on? 
For example I have the following

```
interface MyFilter extends UnaryOperator<MyObject>{};

public MyObject filterIt(List<MyFilter> filters,MyObject obj){
Optional<MyFilter> mf = filters
                           .stream()
                           .reduce( (f1,f2)->(MyFilter)f1.andThen(f2));

return mf.map(f->f.apply(obj)).orElse(obj);

}
```

But this code throws a `ClassCastException` at `(MyFilter)f1.andThen(f2)`.
I really want the effect of this code in the end:

```
MyObject o = obj;
for(MyFilter f:filters){
  o = f.apply(o);
}
return o;
```

But I am also curious of how we can reduce a collection of functions to one function, using `compose` or `andThen`.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The problem with using `compose` or `andThen` is that they're built into the `Function` interface and the type -- both compile-time and runtime types -- of the functions they return is `Function` and not `UnaryOperator` or a subinterface such as you've defined. For example, suppose we have

```
UnaryOperator<String> a = s -> s + "bar";
UnaryOperator<String> b = s -> s + s;
```

One might think we could write

```
UnaryOperator<String> c = a.compose(b);
```

but this doesn't work! Instead, one has to write

```
Function<String, String> c = a.compose(b);
```

For this to work, `UnaryOperator` would have to provide covariant overrides of `andThen` and `compose`. (Arguably this is a bug in the API.) You'd do the same in your subinterface. Or, it's simple enough to write out the lambdas by hand. For example,

```
interface MyOperator extends UnaryOperator<String> { }

public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<MyOperator> list =
        Arrays.asList(s -> s + "bar",
                      s -> "[" + s + "]",
                      s -> s + s);

    MyOperator composite =
        list.stream()
            .reduce(s -> s, (a, b) -> s -> b.apply(a.apply(s)));

    System.out.println(composite.apply("foo"));
}
```

This prints out `[foobar][foobar]`. Note that I've used the two-arg form of `reduce` in order to avoid having to deal with `Optional`.

Alternatively, if you're doing function composition a lot, you could reimplement the methods you need in your own interface. It's not too hard. These are based on the implementations in `java.util.Function` but with the concrete `String` type I've been using in this example substituted for the generics.

```
interface MyOperator extends UnaryOperator<String> {
    static MyOperator identity() {
        return s -> s;
    }

    default MyOperator andThen(MyOperator after) {
        Objects.requireNonNull(after);
        return s -> after.apply(this.apply(s));
    }

    default MyOperator compose(MyOperator before) {
        Objects.requireNonNull(before);
        return s -> this.apply(before.apply(s));
    }
}
```

This would be used as follows:

```
MyOperator composite =
    list.stream()
        .reduce(MyOperator.identity(), (a, b) -> a.andThen(b));
```

Whether bulking up the interface in order to write `andThen` instead of a nested lambda is a matter of taste, I guess.

Comment: Great answer thanks. And a plus for the two-arg reduce form to get rid of the Optional.

Answer (score 8):

It's possible to convert a functional interface to another functional interface by means of using a method reference syntax on its abstract method.

```
import java.util.function.UnaryOperator;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class Example {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Stream<UnaryOperator<String>> stringMappers = Stream.of(
                s -> s + "bar",
                s -> "[" + s + "]",
                s -> s + s
        );
        UnaryOperator<String> f = stringMappers.reduce(
                s -> s,
                (a, b) -> a.andThen(b)::apply
        );
        System.out.println(f.apply("foo"));
    }
}
```

Comment: The recommendation to use '::apply' helped me. Better than the advice given in the preferred answer, namely to abandon UnaryOperator and switch to Function.

Answer (score 6):

`MyFilter` inherits the method `andThen` from `Function` and therefore the returned type is `Function` and cannot be cast to `MyFilter`. But since it has the desired function signature, you can create the `MyFilter` instance using a lambda or method reference.

E.g. change `(f1,f2)->(MyFilter)f1.andThen(f2)` to `(f1,f2)-> f1.andThen(f2)::apply`.

With this change the entire method looks like:

```
public static MyObject filterIt(List<MyFilter> filters, MyObject obj) {
    Optional<MyFilter> mf =
      filters.stream().reduce( (f1,f2)-> f1.andThen(f2)::apply);
    return mf.map(f->f.apply(obj)).orElse(obj);
}
```

But you should rethink your design. There is no need to have the resulting function to be an instance of `MyFilter`, in fact, even the input can be relaxed to accept more than just `List<MyFilter>`:

```
// will accept List<MyFilter> as input
public static MyObject filterIt(
 List<? extends Function<MyObject,MyObject>> filters, MyObject obj) {
   List<Function<MyObject,MyObject>> l=Collections.unmodifiableList(filters);
   Optional<Function<MyObject,MyObject>> mf=l.stream().reduce(Function::andThen);
   return mf.orElse(Function.identity()).apply(obj);
}
```

or, using Stuart Marks’ hint for getting rid of the `Optional`:

```
// will accept List<MyFilter> as input
public static MyObject filterIt(
  List<? extends Function<MyObject,MyObject>> filters,MyObject obj) {
    List<Function<MyObject,MyObject>> l=Collections.unmodifiableList(filters);
    return l.stream().reduce(Function.identity(), Function::andThen).apply(obj);
}
```

---

Just for completeness, alternatively you could chain your `MyFilter`s on a stream rather than composing a new function:

```
public static MyObject filterIt2(List<MyFilter> filters,MyObject obj) {
    Stream<MyObject> s=Stream.of(obj);
    for(MyFilter f: filters) s=s.map(f);
    return s.findAny().get();
}
```

Comment: Also a great and complete answer. Your final code is the alternative I was looking for thanks.

Comment: Quick question, does the Collections.unmodifiableList optimize the stream() and reduce() being slightly more immutable than the original list?

Comment: No, I don’t expect any difference. It only serves as a type-safe conversion from `List<? extends X>` to `List<X>` here.

Answer (score 3):

You can do a cast to `Function<?, ?>` before doing the reduction:

```
interface MyFilter extends UnaryOperator<MyObject>{};

Function<MyObject, MyObject> mf = filters.stream()
    .map(f -> (Function<MyObject, MyObject>) f)
    .reduce(Function.identity(), Function::compose);
```

This lets you use the `Function.identity()` and `Function::compose` methods, avoiding the need to reimplement them in your interface (like Stuart Marks suggested).

The cast is always safe because its up/widening.

Comment: If a typed reference is required, one can use `MyFilter mfTyped = mf::apply;` to convert between `Function<T ,T>` and `UnaryOperator<T>`

Answer (score 2):

A short answer: Never use the interface `UnaryOperator<T>`, use `Function<T, T>` instead. If you do that, the methods compose and `andThen` will work as expected.