# Stream of Function[]

Tags: java, functional-programming, java-stream

how can i use Stream for Function[]? My solution looks very ugly plus i know that this can be done by using reduce().

```
class A {   
    static void run() {
        Integer a = applyConversions(3, x -> x * 3, x -> x + 4);                  // output: 13

        String b = applyConversions("One", s -> "Two " + s, String::toUpperCase); // output: OneTwo
    }

    static <T> T applyConversions(T value, Function<T, T>... conversions) {
        /*
        todo: apply each conversion function to 'value'

        ==>My Ugly solution<==
        final Object[] valueHelper = {null};
        valueHelper[0] = value;
        Stream.of(conversions).forEach(s-> valueHelper[0] = s.apply((T)valueHelper[0]));
        return (T)valueHelper[0];
        */
        return value;
    }
}
```

I can change only signature and body of 'applyConversions' method

Comment: The second example is supposed to produce "ONETWO", right?

Comment: @Sweeper Reading the code, it should be `TWO ONE` if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: @VincentC. Oh yes you're right!

Comment: You don't really need a `Function<T,T>`, a `UnaryOperator<T>` would be more clear. This would be a good reference- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24006489/reducing-a-list-of-unaryoperators-in-java-8

Comment: @VincentC. Yes, my bad

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to want to `reduce` the functions using [`andThen`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Function.html#andThen-java.util.function.Function-). Assuming `conversions` can't be empty, you can do:

```
static <T> T applyConversions(T value, Function<T, T>... conversions) {
    return Arrays.stream(conversions).reduce(Function::andThen).get().apply(value);
}
```

If it can be empty, you need to decide what to return when it is empty.

```
return Arrays.stream(conversions).reduce(Function::andThen)
        .map(x -> x.apply(value)).orElse(someDefaultValue);
```

If you want it to use `value` as the default value, you do `orElse(Function.identity())` instead of `get`ting the optional.

```
return Arrays.stream(conversions)
   .reduce(Function::andThen).orElse(Function.identity())
   .apply(value);
```

Comment: `Function.identity` can be used with the overloaded `reduce` API.

Comment: You can fuse your first and third solution to one function, using `.reduce(Function::andThen).orElse(Function.identity())`, having the advantages of both, not combining existing functions with the identity function, but handling an empty array gracefully. Side note, this method is a candidate for `@SafeVarargs`. Its further worth noting that combining functions this way creates an unbalanced tree, so this method should not be used with overly long arrays, as evaluating the combined may risk a `StackOverflowError`.

Comment: @Holger Is "combining existing functions with the identity function" somehow _bad_?

Comment: I’d say, for a temporary function, the additional memory consumption doesn’t matter. Still, the result is an unbalanced tree whose evaluation has to traverse it. Such a throwaway function has little chances to get entirely inlined, so it may have an effect on the performance. There’s also a slightly higher risk of a stack overflow. And giving, how the Hotspot JVM works, with its default max inlining threshold of nine, one more function can have a surprisingly bad effect on the performance. Besides that, why did you keep the first version, when not for that reason?

Comment: @Holger The first version was meant as a fail-fast, to catch situations where `conversions` is unexpectedly empty. I wish I can think about problems as deeply as you do! :-)

Comment: It’s a matter of experience. I already discussed the implication of combining functions via reduction in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59885137/2711488). It combines `Consumer` instances, but the logic is the same for `Function`.