# Stream / Reduce a series of functions applied to an input value with bound variables in Java

Tags: java, java-stream

How does one go about rewriting this loop using a stream.

```
private final List<RegionSpecificValidator> validators;
public Item applyValidations(Item inbound, Holder holder, Product product) {
    Item toValidate = inbound;
    for (var validator: validators)
        toValidate = validator.validate(toValidate, holder, product);
    return toValidate;
}
```

It should be possible to rewrite this loop using `validators.stream().reduce(...)`

I have tried using the guidance here, but I cannot figure out what BiFunction interface needs to be implemented and how.
The interface as it currently stands looks like this:

```
public interface RegionSpecificValidator {
    Item validate(Item toValidate, Holder holder, Product product);
}
```

I have looked at this guidance: [Reducing a list of UnaryOperators in Java 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24006489/reducing-a-list-of-unaryoperators-in-java-8)
However it's not clear how I implement `andThen` in this case, or even if it's possible.

Comment: What do the specific validators return in case of success/failure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the [reduce() method with transformer and combiner](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#reduce-U-java.util.function.BiFunction-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-).

The three arguments are as follows:

- `inbound` is the base case. For example, if `validators` is an empty list, it is the object that is returned by default
- `(toValidate, validator) -> validator.validate(toValidate, holder, product)` it takes an `Item` and a `validator` and produces an `Item`. This happens via the `validate()` method on the validator.
- `(prev, next) -> next` defines how reduction should happen between two items - you need to pick one. In your `for`-loop you are always overwriting `toValidate` with the new value, so in this case we should return `next`, i.e. the last element that we obtained from `validator.validate()`.

```java
public Item applyValidations(Item inbound, Holder holder, Product product) {
    return validators.stream().reduce(
        inbound, 
        (toValidate, validator) -> validator.validate(toValidate, holder, product), 
        (prev, next) -> next
    );
}
```

Comment: @Jim I would rethink if this is more reasonable code than the `for` loop though, which IMO is more readable.

Answer (score 0):

You could also reduce all your validators into a single one using something like this:

```java
RegionSpecificValidator validator = validators.stream().reduce(
    (i, h, p) -> i,
    (a, b) -> (i, h, p) -> b.validate(a.validate(i, h, p), h, p)
);
```

- `(i, h, p) -> i`: the initial validator, just returns the input item. Needed, because the single parameter `reduce()` method returns an `Optional` and we don't want that here.
- `(a, b) -> (i, h, p) -> b.validate(a.validate(i, h, p), h, p)`: When written out, it may make more sense:

  ```java
  (a, b) -> {                         // `a` and `b` are both validators
      return (i, h, p) -> {           // create a new implementation of the validator interface
          i = a.validate(i, h, p);    // the result from `a` will be saved 
          return b.validate(r, h, p); // and then passed to `b`
      }
  }
  ```

  This code "merges" two validators together, applying the parameters to the first, and then using that returned `Item` as an argument to be passed to the next validator. Both of these are then wrapped inside a lambda of type `RegionSpecificValidator`. Note that this will only work when `RegionSpecificValidator` is a functional interface. (One and only one `abstract` method in the `interface`)

---

This could also be only done once (iff `validators` is immutable and given at the class' creation time):

```java
private final RegionSpecificValidator validator;

public YourClass(List<Validator> validators) {
    this.valdiator = validators.stream().reduce(
        (i, h, p) -> i,
        (a, b) -> (i, h, p) -> b.validate(a.validate(i, h, p), h, p)
    );
}

public Item applyValidations(Item inbound, Holder holder, Product product) {
    return validator.validate(inbound, holder, product);
}
```